# signalR Hub negotiate fails when deploying to IIS

Tags: iis, signalr

When I deploy my signalR Hub to my local machine's IIS, it seems to run just fine under `http://localhost:5527` - however my front end cannot connect.

***Front End Errors:***

`POST http://localhost:55271/hub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1 404 (Not Found)`
`Utils.js:198 [2020-07-23T17:35:48.643Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Not Found`
`[2020-07-23T17:35:48.648Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Not Found`

**IN DEBUG MODE:** in vs2019 debug mode, everything works fine:

[image]

[image]

---

**IIS**

I added a new Website in IIS on my Win 10 box, set the path to `C:\dev\git-projects\myProject\WebApp\NotificationsHub\NotificationsHub`, and also set the bindings:

[image]
[image]

**Web.Config**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Request-Headers" value="User-Agent,Content-Type,Authorization,X-RequestDigest,X-ClientService-ClientTag,XMLHttpRequest,x-requested-with" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="User-Agent,Content-Type,Authorization,X-RequestDigest,X-ClientService-ClientTag,XMLHttpRequest,x-requested-with" />
          <!-- not sure if really needed; also see AllowAnyMethod() in startup.cs -->
          <add name="Access-Control-Request-Method" value="GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**C# Hub Project, startup.cs:**

```js
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {            
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowedSpecificOrigins,
                                    builder =>
                                    {                                        
                                        // without .AllowAnyMethod() we might get a request method cors error in debug mode.
                                        builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                                    });
            });        

            services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {
                hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
                hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000);
            });            
        }
```

**Front end Angular 9 code, snippet from notification.service.ts:**

```js
public startConnection = () => {
    let url = this.config.getConfig('notificationsUrl'); // currently "http://localhost:55271/hub"
    
    const sessionNum = this.appSession.session == undefined ? '' : this.appSession.session.SessionID;
    this.hubConnection = new signalr.HubConnectionBuilder()
                            .withUrl(url, {accessTokenFactory: () => sessionNum})
                            .configureLogging(signalr.LogLevel.Debug)
                            .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() =>  {
        this.hubListener();     // setup some event listeners
        this.hubDisconnected();     
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(`Error while starting connection: ${err}`));

    this.hubConnection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 50000;
  }
```

Any help is appreciated to figure out what's wrong with my IIS deployment, and why I cannot make a Hub connection from the front end (i.e. again, all is fine when my IIS site is down, and I'm debugging in vs2019 with IIS express).

Comment: Try to configure CORS on backend like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958384/javascript-xmlhttp-error-on-signalr-in-asp-net-core/62958670#62958670

Comment: Have you get both static file and IIS asp.net extension installed? If the handler can't handle extensionless URL, IIS will also return 404 error.

Comment: @JokiesDing - I only installed the cors module for IIS, based on a previous post. But now that my IIS cors issue is resolved, I will have to try the iis asp.net extension. thanks.

Comment: @Kiril1512 - yes, and thank you for that. In fact it's already in my web.config above. But I also tried the other way as per the so link you posted. It could be that I'm missing the asp.net extension for IIS mentioned by Jokies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my colleague help me with deploying the .Net Core signalR project to my local `IIS 10` instance.

We ended up using the VS2019 `Publish` tool, and pushed the files to a new folder under inetpub - `c:\inetpub\www\NotifHub`.

This ended up creating all the required files for my Notification site. It worked successfully, and the front end successfully sends the `hub/negotiate` request.

***IIS Screenshot:***

[image]

***Chrome console:***

[image: Front end TypeScript code with successful Hub connection]

***Previous problem:*** I was pointing my IIS website's `physical path` to C:\dev\git-projects\MyStuff\WebApp\NotificationsHub\NotificationsHub, which was the way we would do it for framework 4.x projects (i.e. testing API projects in local dev envir). In this case it appears that IIS couldn't locate the release files to execute.